# How to predict what will damage or heal an opponent?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

On several occasions our actions ***healed*** our enemies, where there was no apparent clue that this would happen. Surely there *is* such a clue, and we just don't see it. I'm here to ask if anyone can enlighten us.

**How can you tell if your action will *heal* instead of *hurt* the opponent?**

Here's an example situation that highly confused me. We got into a fight with a Goblin named Kadraskaz, and *all* of the following seemed to *heal* him:

- Pyrokenetics spells such as Burning Blaze (Fire);
- Geomancy spells such as Boulder Bash (Earth) and Magical Poison Arrow (Poison);
- Aerotheurgy spells such as Headvice (Air);
- Hitting him with a staff that does Water damage;
- The Earth-damage from a Piercing weapon (the piercing damage was normal);

This was the enemy's status at the time:

[image: Kadraskaz' status]

The fact that I started my question saying we had "no clue" that the enemy would be healed was because I figured that "*Resistance*" would worst-case reduce damage to zero; but perhaps  "*Resistance*" from a certain point (100?) onward should be interpreted as "*Will actually heal the guy*"? In my example above that would mean only physical damage was useful, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sir, you should research your question better. The [Divinity: Original Sin Wikia has a page](http://divinity.wikia.com/wiki/Divinity:_Original_Sin_Defenses#Resistances) that contains the answer you already hint at (emphasis mine):

> **Resistances over 100 turn the damage dealt into healing**, so that 175 Fire Resistance means the creature heals for 75% of any fire damage dealt to it.

The other way around, negative resistance will *amplify* damage, and 0-100 resistance will be "resistance" in the traditional meaning of the word.

Mentioned Wikia page also suggests this works similarly for physical damage types (e.g. "Piercing"), though you'd need to find an opponent with 100+ "resistance" to verify that.